# Action controller exception caught, NoMethodError in Bookings#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make an app where an user can make a book in a hour of training.

This is my Bookings controller:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_training,  only: [:create]

  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
    @booking.training_id
  end

  def create
    @booking = @training.bookings.build(booking_params)
    @booking.user = current_user.id

    if @booking.save
      flash[:success] = "Book created"
      redirect_to training_index_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end


  def index
    @booking = Booking.all
  end


  def destroy
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    @booking.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Book deleted"
    redirect_to training_index_url
  end



private
  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:user_id, :training_id)
  end

  def load_training
    @training = Training.find(params[:booking][:training_id])
  end

end
```

This is my Booking model:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :training
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :training_id, presence: true



end
```

When I try to make the book in the training I get the following error:

> NoMethodError in Bookings#new Showing
>   /home/cesar/Apps/boxApp/app/views/bookings/new.html.erb where line #6
>   raised:
>
> undefined method `bookings_path' for
>   <#:0x0055c4717cc4d8> Did you mean?  book_path

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get    '/signup',               to: 'users#new'
  get    '/contact',              to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get    '/about',                to: 'static_pages#about'
  get    '/login',                to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',                to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',               to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get    '/book',                 to: 'bookings#new'
  post   '/book',                 to: 'bookings#create'
  delete '/unbook',               to: 'bookings#destroy'


  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]

  resources :trainings do
    resources :bookings
  end
  resources :users
end
```

My new.html.erb Booking view:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<%= form_for ([@training, @booking]) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :training_id %>
<%= f.submit "Confirm book", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to now why I get this error and how can I fix it so the book can be successfully done.

The show.html.erb Training view:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Clase | Ludus app') %>
<div class="row">
    <section>
      <h1>
HOUR: <%= @training.hour %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <section>
      <h1>
SLOTS: <%= @training.slots %>
      </h1>
    </section>
    <center>
    <%= render 'bookings/booking_form' if logged_in? %>
    <%= render 'bookings/show_bookings' if logged_in? %>
  </center>
```

The booking_form:

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
      <% if current_user.bookings(@training) %>
        <%= link_to "Book", new_training_booking_path(@training), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Output of rake routes command:

```
                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                         Controller#Action
                   root GET    /                                                   static_pages#home
                 signup GET    /signup(.:format)                                   users#new
                contact GET    /contact(.:format)                                  static_pages#contact
                  about GET    /about(.:format)                                    static_pages#about
                  login GET    /login(.:format)                                    sessions#new
                        POST   /login(.:format)                                    sessions#create
                 logout DELETE /logout(.:format)                                   sessions#destroy
                   book GET    /book(.:format)                                     bookings#new
                        POST   /book(.:format)                                     bookings#create
                 unbook DELETE /unbook(.:format)                                   bookings#destroy
edit_account_activation GET    /account_activations/:id/edit(.:format)             account_activations#edit
        password_resets POST   /password_resets(.:format)                          password_resets#create
     new_password_reset GET    /password_resets/new(.:format)                      password_resets#new
    edit_password_reset GET    /password_resets/:id/edit(.:format)                 password_resets#edit
         password_reset PATCH  /password_resets/:id(.:format)                      password_resets#update
                        PUT    /password_resets/:id(.:format)                      password_resets#update
      training_bookings GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings(.:format)          bookings#index
                        POST   /trainings/:training_id/bookings(.:format)          bookings#create
   new_training_booking GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/new(.:format)      bookings#new
  edit_training_booking GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id/edit(.:format) bookings#edit
       training_booking GET    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#show
                        PATCH  /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#update
                        PUT    /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#update
                        DELETE /trainings/:training_id/bookings/:id(.:format)      bookings#destroy
              trainings GET    /trainings(.:format)                                trainings#index
                        POST   /trainings(.:format)                                trainings#create
           new_training GET    /trainings/new(.:format)                            trainings#new
          edit_training GET    /trainings/:id/edit(.:format)                       trainings#edit
               training GET    /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#show
                        PATCH  /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#update
                        PUT    /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#update
                        DELETE /trainings/:id(.:format)                            trainings#destroy
                  users GET    /users(.:format)                                    users#index
                        POST   /users(.:format)                                    users#create
               new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                users#new
              edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                           users#edit
                   user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                users#show
                        PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                users#update
                        PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                users#update
                        DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                users#destroy
```

Comment: What is the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: Try `training_bookings_path(@training)` and run `load_training` in controller before `index` action too.

Comment: training_bookings_path should be there

Comment: updated with rake routes

Answer (score 0):

> NoMethodError in Bookings#new Showing
>   /home/cesar/Apps/boxApp/app/views/bookings/new.html.erb where line #6
>   raised:
>
> undefined method `bookings_path' for <#:0x0055c4717cc4d8> Did you
>   mean? book_path

You have `<%= form_for ([@training, @booking]) do |f| %>` in `new.html.erb`, but `@training` is ***not available*** for `new` method. <s>since you have set the `before_action` ***only for create*** method.</s>

<s>Changing</s>

```
before_action :load_training,  only: [:create]
```

to

```
before_action :load_training,  only: [:new,:create]
```

should fix the error.

Changing your `new` method like below should fix the error

```
def new
  @booking = Booking.new
  @training = Training.find(params[:training_id])
  @booking.training_id
end
```

Comment: ok it looks like it worked, but now i recieve the following error: "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BookingsController#create
Couldn't find Training with 'id'="

Parameters:  "booking"=>{"training_id"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Book confirmation",
 "training_id"=>"11"}


Its not taking the training_id into the booking, do you know why?